Using FFTW3 plan for repeated use
As the documentation says that fftw3 plan can be reused with different values if the array remains same. I'm using the following statement to create the plan p in Fortran.
call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(plan,N,fin,fout,FFTW_ESTIMATE)

However, the above statement is used through a subroutine away from the main program and will be repeatedly called with different values of fin with the same size. My present strategy is as follows:
subroutine fft_forward(fin,fout)
  implicit none
  integer(8),save :: plan
  integer,save    :: first=0
  double precision,dimension(:) :: fin
  double complex,dimension(:)   :: fout
  integer :: N
  
  N = size(fin)
  if (first == 0) then
    call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(plan,N,fin,fout,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    first = 1
  endif
  call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan,fin,fout)
  ...
  ...
end subroutine

Is the right way to do? I'm confused about saving the variable plan during repeated calling of the subroutine.

Yes it is one way. But I'd pass it as an argument, keep your procedures pure wherever possible

BTW if you insist on this way making first Logical seems more natural in Fortran.
